# Why can't I enumerate through items in this collection:?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Aren't arrays of object enumerable?

Look for the comments in the code

```
Public Class AddressCollection

    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of AddressType)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal ParamArray addressTypeArray() As AddressType)

        For Each currentAddress As AddressType In Me

            If currentAddress IsNot Nothing Then '<<<<--NEVER HITS THIS LINE
                Me.Add(currentAddress)
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To addressTypeArray.Count - 1

            Dim currentAddress As AddressType = addressTypeArray(i) '<<< BUT IT DOES HIT THIS LINE

            If currentAddress IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.Add(currentAddress)
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: If it wasn't enumerable it wouldn't compile... You don't show a full scenario here... What is the caller supplying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want:

```
For Each currentAddress As AddressType In addressTypeArray
```

.. to match the equivalent of:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To addressTypeArray.Count - 1
```

Answer (score 7):

They do. But wouldn't you rather like to iterate over `addressTypeArray`, not `Me`? `Me` is still empty in the constructor I guess, and that's why you never hit the line.

Cheers, Matthias

Answer (score 2):

Why should it? You are in the constructor of your class and no objects have been added to the collection represented by your class... To verify this, check the result of `Me.Count` before the first `For Each`. It will be 0. I suppose, you really want to iterate over the supplied parameter `addressTypeArray`.